# Cannot do mpmath.sqrtm() in sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I have the following code to extract the square root of a symmetric second-order tensor.

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, mpmath
import numpy as np

F11, F12, F13, F21, F22, F23, F31, F32, F33 = symbols('F11, F12, F13, F21, F22, F23, F31, F32, F33', real=True)
F = np.array([[F11, F12, F13], [F21, F22, F23], [F31, F32, F33]])
B = F.dot(F.T)
mpmath.sqrtm(Matrix(B))
```

However, it gave me the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-439fed475a57> in <module>()
      5 F = np.array([[F11, F12, F13], [F21, F22, F23], [F31, F32, F33]])
      6 B = F.dot(F.T)
----> 7 mpmath.sqrtm(Matrix(B))

X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\matrices\calculus.py in sqrtm(ctx, A, _may_rotate)
    308 
    309         """
--> 310         A = ctx.matrix(A)
    311         # Trivial
    312         if A*0 == A:

X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\matrices\matrices.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    326                     A[i,j] = convert(A[i,j])
    327         elif hasattr(args[0], 'tolist'):
--> 328             A = self.ctx.matrix(args[0].tolist())
    329             self.__data = A._matrix__data
    330             self.__rows = A._matrix__rows

X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\matrices\matrices.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    299                 for i, row in enumerate(A):
    300                     for j, a in enumerate(row):
--> 301                         self[i, j] = convert(a)
    302             else:
    303                 # interpret list as row vector

X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\ctx_mp_python.py in convert(ctx, x, strings)
    660         if hasattr(x, '_mpmath_'):
    661             return ctx.convert(x._mpmath_(prec, rounding))
--> 662         return ctx._convert_fallback(x, strings)
    663 
    664     def isnan(ctx, x):

X:\WinPython3\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\ctx_mp.py in _convert_fallback(ctx, x, strings)
    612             else:
    613                 raise ValueError("can only create mpf from zero-width interval")
--> 614         raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))
    615 
    616     def mpmathify(ctx, *args, **kwargs):

TypeError: cannot create mpf from F11**2 + F12**2 + F13**2
```

May I ask why that is happening? Is this a limitation of `sympy` or that I am doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Shawn

Answer (score 1):

mpmath.sqrtm is expecting a square matrix of numbers; if you want to take the sqrt of each element in B *symbolically* try:

```
>>> B.applyfunc(sqrt)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to do the matrix sqrt though, not element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use NumPy to do symbolic calculations. NumPy only works with numerical arrays.

To take the square root of a matrix, use `B**(Rational(1, 2))` (`sqrt(B)` ought to work too, but it looks like it remains unevaluated by default).

In this case, though, SymPy hangs, because it computes the square root by diagonalizing, and the eigenvalues don't simplify (or at least SymPy doesn't know how to simplify them), so they are huge cubic equations. Take a look at `B.eigenvals()`. Thus, the square root of this matrix is quite huge. Are you expecting the square root matrix to be a relatively simple expression?

Comment: Thank you for your response! And I actually know that it is going to be a super-long expression. What I planned to do is to just get this long expression and plug it into other formula, where it would eventually cancel a lot of terms and becomes simple.

Comment: And thanks for the tip in not using numpy! I used numpy because I need to work with 4-th order tensors, and I need numpy.outer(). Should I use numpy.outer() on sympy.Matrix? I noticed that they just work too.